# Squared first derivative

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone give a hint as to how to solve a differential equation of the form $$(y')^2=\sum_{i=0}^3 c_iy^i$$ where $y=y(x)$ and $c_i$ are constants? I don't know if this is relevant but it is given that $y'(x),y''(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the square root and dividing by the right-hand side yields and integral like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210122), an elliptic integral that can't be solved with elementary functions for general $c_i$.